# Reading multiple txt files from multiple folders in Java

Tags: java, file, text-files

This is the data structure in my computer.

```
amdar(folder) / 20141125(folder) / 300++ txt files
              / 20141126(folder) / 300++ txt files
              / 20141127(folder) / 300++ txt files ...
              / 20141128(folder) / 300++ txt files ...
              / 20141129(folder) / 300++ txt files ...
             ... daily folders are added on and on ...   `
```

I want to read each folder along with 300++ txt files with Java. For doing so, I used two loops: one for folders and another for txt files of the folders. First for loop for the folders worked well. Second nested for loop for the txt files went awry. While the folders begin from 20141125, the read txt files started from somewhere in the 20141128 folder; so many txt files in the folders: 20141125 ~ 20141128 were not read. Please see the screenshot below.

[[Screenshot: Why are the txt files from the 20141125 folder not shown first and even not shown at all?]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvZuF.jpg)

To solve this issue, instead of nested for loop, I tried to use while and separate method, but the result(error), not starting to read from the beginning folder, was the same. Based on the code below, I don't find any reason making this issue happen. Can you explain why? Thank you.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File dir = new File("c:\\html_test\\amdar");
        File[] folder = dir.listFiles();
            for(File table : folder) {
                System.out.println(table);
                File[] filenames = table.listFiles();
                    for (File file : filenames) {
                        System.out.println(file);
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I modified the code. And I succeeded creating tables, reading a single txt file. But the issues starts only when I tried to read multiple folders and multiple txt files within them. I felt like it was an internal error in Java since I tried several methods.

Comment: Better, but still : read [mcve] and clearly describe what you expect your code to do, and what actually happens. I would also suggest that you remove anything that doesn't relate to your specific problem. Better ask 10 different clear questions than one that talks about 5 or 10 different aspects of your overall task!

Comment: Again, much better! I am busy right now, but I hope a good answer comes by soon.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! Your directive has made my question much cleaner and clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Right click on the console > Preferences > Console buffer size.
> Uncheck the "Limit console output" checkbox.
```

There was no error in my code.

It was just that the result had been truncated by the 80000 character limit.

I released the limit and got the result that I expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
Code written for to read multiple test files from multiple folder: 
In the try block the FileReader reads a file and the second works as a constructor parameter and has a readline() method.


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String dir = "c:\\html_test\\amdar";
        File dir = new File(dir);
            File[] folder = dir.listFiles();

        for(File table : folder) {
        if(table.isFile())
        {  
            BufferedReader inputStream = null;      
        try{
            inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String line;
            while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) 
             {
               System.out.println(line);
              }

            }  
             finally {
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                        }           

                     }
        }
              }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't just drop code. Always give a bit of explanation to it.

Comment: @GhostCat added some explanation for my answer!

Comment: Please use try with resource instead of doing manual finally blocks. That is so pre 2010.

Comment: @Varcha Nadar Thank you but when I copied your code into my Eclipse, due to lots of red lines I couldn't execute. Could you please review it? 

And, I am going to use BufferedReader only after I resolve the error that I encountered, which is not showing all the titles of txt files. I am not ready to do BufferedReader yet because I can't even call all the titles of txt files yet.